# Term filter inside decay function

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this block of query function score

```
  "must": {
    "function_score": {
      "min_score":0.1,
      "boost": 1,
      "functions": [
        {
          //i want to do term filter here
          //"query" : {"term": {"location_type":"landmark"} },
          "linear": {
            "coordinates": {
              "offset": "500m",
              "origin": [
                106.8456,
                -6.2088
              ],
              "scale": "1m"
            }
          }
        },
        { //another function here}
      ]
    }
  }
```

My question now is, it is possible to do term filtering together with linear decay function in elasticsearch?

So I will be showing items inside the coordinates and with location_type of landmark only.

Noted that I am not able to do the term filtering in the function score block or the block above, since I will add another function which will do similar things. So different filtering for each function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `filter` keyword instead of `query` and then it will work:

```
  "must": {
    "function_score": {
      "min_score":0.1,
      "boost": 1,
      "functions": [
        {
  -->     "filter" : {"term": {"location_type":"landmark"} },
          "linear": {
            "coordinates": {
              "offset": "500m",
              "origin": [
                106.8456,
                -6.2088
              ],
              "scale": "1m"
            }
          }
        },
        { //another function here}
      ]
    }
  }
```